# Silvermoreto's Bootstrap Select not working as intended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-select

I am trying to create a bootstrap select list in a html file using Dreamweaver CS6 preview. I have the following code that should work, but it doesn't show the select box as it should - when you select an item a tick should appear next to that item. Also the appearance of the box looks different to the example on http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <span class="label label-default">Default</span>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); </script>  

    <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>3">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
        <option>Onions</option>
    </select>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
        <br> <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with your code. Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cuovoqzw/

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<span class="label label-default">Default</span>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>3">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
    <option>Onions</option>
</select>

<form action="welcome.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email">
    <br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

The most probable reason I see is that you've included multiple instances of Bootstrap CSS files in your code. Just include only the required ones and delete the rest.